# Duplicates in sphinxsearch 2.2.4 wordforms dictionary contains only one line

Tags: linux, dictionary, configuration, 64-bit, sphinx

I have problem with my fresh compiled 2.2.4 sphinx installation.

Binaries were built with parameters:

```
$ ./configure --without-pgsql --with-mysql --enable-id64 --prefix=/usr/local/sphinxsearch/2.2.4 --with-mysql-libs=/usr/bin
```

For testing I created wordform dictionary with only one line. I removed old indexes, and try to create new indexes with command:

```
 /usr/bin/indexer --rotate --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf indexname
```

which gave me result:

```
Sphinx 2.2.4-id64-release (r4806)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'indexname'...
WARNING: index 'indexname': duplicate wordform found ( 'yes > now' ). Fix your wordforms   file '/var/lib/sphinxsearch/wordforms.txt'.
```

my configuration:

```
index indexname
{
source              = indexsource
path                = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/index
dict = keywords
docinfo             = extern
min_word_len        = 2 
wordforms    =  /var/lib/sphinxsearch/wordforms.txt 
}
```

So my question is this: How can I configure sphinx with wordforms properly. With 2.1.9 version there were no such problems

**Additional info:**

Today I try to build 2.2.3-beta version, and guess what? Problem not exists. So there must be problem with new stable 2.2.4 version :(

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm I also had this issue with 2.2.4. I upgrade to 2.2.6 this morning and the warning has gone without any changes to my config.